Is there any philosopher of science who advocates for the same epistemology defended by Isaac Asimov in his essay "The Relativity of Wrong"?
I recently re-read the famous essay by Isaac Asimov, "The Relativity of Wrong".
Of course this is just an informal presentation of Asimov's own view about science, but I wonder if there is any well regarded scholar in the field of philosophy of science who advocates for a similar view, albeit in an academic and rigorous manner.

Bart Kosko is a proponent of fuzzy logic, much to the dislike of those scientists who believe that something is true or false, not a degree of rightness or wrongness.

Linking the essay would be polite.  Doing a google search first, and a search on PhilSE before asking here is also strongly recommended by the site.

Here is the link to  Asimov's essay. I do not know why some passages are highlighted in yellow.

IMO Asimov’s essay describes correctly most phases in the
development of science, so to speak the first approximation of
scientific progress. Asimov closes

“Naturally, the theories we now have might be considered wrong in the
simplistic sense of my English Lit correspondent, but in a much truer
and subtler sense, they need only be considered incomplete.”

With the words of the philosopher Gerhard Vollmer this development
may be characterized as “We err upwards” – originally coined by him
for the idea of Popper’s falsificationism.

According to the philosopher of science Thomas Kuhn in his book “The
structure of scientific revolutions” one has the evolutionary phases
where scientists improve the common paradigm by small steps, on one
hand.
And on the other hand, there are the revolutionary phases
where the common paradigm falls short and gets replaced by the
invention of a new paradigm for science. Examples of the latter
revolutions are the invention of the theory of relativity and of
quantum theory.

The idea of revolutionary phases in science is absent from Asimov’s
view. This insight is due to Kuhn, see The structure of
scientific revolutions.


